# Variable sent through .js file is not recieving by .PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I'm sending a variable from .js file to a PHP file but it always give me an error like this Could someone please help me to sort it out.

. js file................

```
function AddDataRows(){

var retVal = prompt("Enter the number of textboxes need to add");

$.ajax({
 url: 'CreateTheForm.php', //This is the current doc
 type: "POST",
 dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
 data: ({nameee: retVal}),
 success: function(data){
    alert(data);
     console.log(data);
 }
});  
//window.location.href="CreateTheForm.php?rowAddition="+retVal;

}
```

And this is what in the PHP file.

```
if (isset($_POST['nameee'])) $php_var = $_POST['nameee'];
else $php_var = "<br />js_var is not set!";

echo $php_var;
```

But it give me an error like

> Notice: Undefined index: nameee in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHIS\CreateTheForm.php on line 501
>
> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHIS\CreateTheForm.php on line 502

js_var is not set!

In function AddDataRows() variable retVal prints well. But it is not recieving by the PHP fil...

Comment: What exactly does the Network Inspector of your browser say what data is being sent?

Comment: How can you send a function ** prompt("Enter the number of textboxes need to add"); ** as data???

Comment: testing out your function, it seems to send a valid post. Is that all of the php? As metioned above look at the network tab in developer tools, and also see what $POST contains in the php file

Comment: @Ajeet https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt

Comment: Is there anything else in your php file?

Comment: The PHP code you show should also not be producing those exact errors.

Comment: Network tab doesn't show any errors. when I used var_dump($_POST['nameee']) it shows Null. I don't know where do I need to correct...

Comment: Change `data: ({nameee: retVal})` to `data: {nameee: retVal}`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in js

```
function AddDataRows(){

var retVal = prompt("Enter the number of textboxes need to add");

$.ajax({
 url: 'CreateTheForm.php?nameee='+retVal, //This is the current doc
type: "GET",
dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
data: ({'nameee': retVal}),
success: function(data){
alert(data);
console.log(data);
}
});  
//window.location.href="CreateTheForm.php?rowAddition="+retVal;

}
```

And get it in php as

```
 if (isset($_RQUEST['nameee'])) $php_var = $_RQUEST['nameee'];
 else $php_var = "<br />js_var is not set!";

 echo $php_var;
```